Show date upload of attachment on Chatter Odoo 16
I want to show the upload date/create date of an attachment in Chatter for control version upload on Odoo 16. Is there any way to do this? I tried searching but didn't find an answer to this problem.
Sample
attachemnt.js file
/** @odoo-module **/
import { clear } from '@mail/model/model_field_command';
import { attr } from '@mail/model/model_field';

import { registerPatch } from '@mail/model/model_core';

registerPatch({
    name: 'Attachment',
    modelMethods: {
        /**
         * @override
         */
        convertData(data) {
            const res = this._super(data);
            if ('create_date' in data) {
                res.create_date = data.create_date;
            }
            return res;
        },
    },
    fields: {
        create_date: attr({
            compute() {
                const create_date = this.create_date;
                if (create_date) {
                    return create_date;
                }
                return clear();
            },
        }),
    },
});

attachment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<templates xml:space="preserve"> 
    <t t-name='catus.custome_attachment' t-inherit="mail.AttachmentCard" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1" primary="1">
    <xpath expr="//*[hasclass('o_AttachmentCard_filename')]" position="after">
    Date Uploaded: 
    
        <div class="o_AttachmentCard_createdate" t-if="attachmentCard.attachment.create_date">
            <t t-esc="attachmentCard.attachment.create_date"/>
        </div>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//*[hasclass('o_AttachmentCard_extension')]" position="replace">            
            <div></div>
        </xpath> 
    </t>
</templates>

attachment_thread.js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registerPatch } from '@mail/model/model_core';
import { insertAndReplace } from '@mail/model/model_field_command';

registerPatch({
    name: 'Thread',
    modelMethods: {
        async fetchData( requestList) {
            //get create_date to show
            this._super.apply(this, requestList);
            let attachmentsData = await this.async(() => this.env.services.rpc({
                model: 'ir.attachment',
                method: 'search_read',
                domain: [
                    ['res_id', '=', this.id],
                    ['res_model', '=', this.model],
                ],
                fields: ['id', 'name', 'mimetype', 'create_date'],
                orderBy: [{name: 'id', asc: false}],
            }, {shadow: true}));
            this.update({
                originThreadAttachments: insertAndReplace(attachmentsData),
            });
            this.update({ areAttachmentsLoaded: true });
        }
    },
});

The attachment creation date is not yet visible

You need to patch the attachment model and add the upload date field

Hi @Kenly. Thank you very much for answering my question. I've edited the post to add the code I did. But it doesn't seem to be usable yet.

No need to fetch data manually, just override the _attachment_format function to prepare values to be used by the chatter widget
Example:
from odoo import models, fields
from odoo.http import request


class IrAttachment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    def _attachment_format(self, legacy=False):
        safari = request and request.httprequest.user_agent and request.httprequest.user_agent.browser == 'safari'
        res_list = []
        for attachment in self:
            res = {
                'checksum': attachment.checksum,
                'id': attachment.id,
                'filename': attachment.name,
                'name': attachment.name,
                'mimetype': 'application/octet-stream' if safari and attachment.mimetype and 'video' in attachment.mimetype else attachment.mimetype,
                'create_date': attachment.create_date
            }
            if not legacy:
                res['originThread'] = [('insert', {
                    'id': attachment.res_id,
                    'model': attachment.res_model,
                })]
            else:
                res.update({
                    'res_id': attachment.res_id,
                    'res_model': attachment.res_model,
                })
            res_list.append(res)
        return res_list

You can use the js field as follows:
fields: {
    create_date: attr(),
},

If you want a custom format, use a computed field
